# What are these files on my SD-Card?

Tags: external-sd

[image]

How can I delete these files? Doesn't work from file browser.

Comment: Also please check this related question and see if it helps: https://superuser.com/questions/456815/files-names-in-pen-drive-turned-into-gibberish-text

Comment: Are we talking about a real physical SD-Card or ist it the SD-Card section of the Smartphone-internal memory?

Comment: @Robert The card is physical. Tried to format, got an error on the phone. will try on the pc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears like your SD card is corrupted, take backup of your important files and do a format.

Some linux formatting guide can be found here [SD card formatting linux](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458743/can-not-format-my-sd-card)